# How to count the particuler range of elements in an numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array like:

```
import numpy as np

data=np.array([[0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1],
              [0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],
              [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]])
```

Requirement:

Needs to count the number of ones in an array, I can count by using this function.

```
print(np.count_nonzero(data==1))
```

the output I got:

```
11
```

But, one special requirement is needed, like if consecutive ones are more than 3 times then only count the ones, in that case, the excepted count of number ones more than 3 consecutive are 5

expected output:

```
5
```

Comment: Why is the expected output 5 (I see only 4)? Why are you working with a 2D array? What's the full list of "requirements"?

Comment: I just need to count the element 1's if there are more than 3 times(for ex:) repeated consecutively. otherwise, ignore the count

Comment: in another case:
if element value 1 is not repeated more than 3 times we can consider it as 0

Comment: In pure `numpy`: `length = np.diff(np.flatnonzero(np.diff(data, append=0, prepend=0, axis=1)))[::2]; length[length > 3].sum()`

Comment: @Michael smart one (however I think this might require some explanations to the non aficionados :p)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can erode/dilate your data to remove the stretches of less than N consecutive 1s.

```
from scipy.ndimage import binary_erosion, binary_dilation

N = 3
k = np.ones((1, N+1))

binary_dilation(binary_erosion(data, k), k).sum()
```

Output: `5`

Output on `data=np.array([[0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1], [0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]])`: `13`

Answer (score 1):

A simple method would be to use a "running average" of window-size 3 and then compare to `1`.
I still don't understand why the OP is using a 2d array, but instead of changing the example I'll just flatten it out:

```
import numpy as np

data=np.array([[0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1],
               [0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],
               [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]])    

def running_avg(x, N):
    return np.convolve(x, np.ones(N)/N, mode='valid')

print(sum(running_avg(data.flatten(), 3) == 1))
# 4, which is actually the correct answer for the given example data as far as I can tell
```

Comment: for this example:
data=np.array([[0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1],
              [0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0],
              [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]])

def running_avg(x, N):
    return np.convolve(x, np.ones(N)/N, mode='valid')

print(sum(running_avg(data.flatten(), 3) == 1))


output it gives:10
instead of count :12

Comment: Did you mean 13?

Comment: Looking at your example, I'd _want_ an answer of 10. Or are we counting rows and columns separately? the op was not very clear despite being asked about the 2d nature explicitly...